# Android random non repeating string

Tags: android, string, random

I'm making a bingo type game. I have a 5x5 grid of imagebuttons, each with their own textview. When the app starts or is reset, I want each textview to display a random string without any one string being displayed twice during a game. I currently have the strings in a resource array, with 127 items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="tile_text">
    <item>String 1</item>
    <item>String 2</item>
    <item>String 3</item>
    ...all the way to String 127
</string-array>
</resources>
```

And to display a random string on each textview:

```
public String[] myString;

Resources res = getResources();
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.tile_text);

Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int[] textViews = {

//I have all my textviews added to this array
};

for(int v : textViews) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(v);

        tv.setText(myString[random.nextInt(myString.length)]);          
}
```

The above works well, but even with 200 strings in the array to choose from, some items still show up twice. Is there a way I can get the array to shuffle and not pick the same string twice for per game? I have searched and I find info on random strings, but nothing about non repeating random strings, so apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep a list of the strings you'e already added and then keep picking new random strings until you find one that's not already in your list.

Something like this:

```
Vector<String> alreadyUsed = new Vector<String>();

for(int v : textViews) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(v);

    String nextString;
    do {
        nextString = myString[random.nextInt(myString.length)];                
    } while (alreadyUsed.contains(nextString));
    alreadyUsed.add(nextString);

    tv.setText(nextString);          
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! I also added alreadyUsed.clear() outside of the for loop, so that it can choose from all the strings again each new game, but it doesn't add the same string(s) more than once each game.